# How do I return several consecutive from a string? vb

Tags: vb.net, console-application

Trying to create a small Visual Basic console application in visual studio here. I need to obtain a couple of consecutive characters from a string entered by the user. I know how to return one character from a string using the getchar( 'string name', 'where is char you want located') but am not aware on how to obtain several consecutive chars. If there's way to do something like: getchar(string, count, count + 1, count + 2) that'd be great to know. And i'm not very experienced with visual basic or any type of code at all so keeping it simple and understandable would really be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Oh plod I meant vb.net sorry

Comment: In that case, you can simply use `Mid(string, count, 3)`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) function.